# Parse SIP Register Method

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am developing SIP register method in C#. My response:

> SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required Via: SIP/2.0/UDP
>   192.168.1.33:5701;branch=z9hG4bK5b5077e0-e26f-4a50-bf16-10b5b22b591c;rport=61440
>   Proxy-Authenticate: Digest
>   nonce="414d535c055d02e522:529160ab400aa5fa69724cb6e8554e36",algorithm=MD5,realm="3CXPhoneSystem"
>   To: "102";tag=ee588151 From:
>   "102";tag=hetfgeeb Call-ID:
>   gdhisemewofqcjxysiwjjnrtfdwsfcmykvspmdxfnpllcrdsyi CSeq: 1 REGISTER
>   User-Agent: 3CXPhoneSystem 10.0.22539.0 Content-Length: 0

How can I parse "nonce" value using regex?

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
(?<=nonce=").*?(?=")
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?305cs)

If you want a more detailed answer, provide more details.